# which algorithm should i use for file path matching

Tags: java

i need to check if some file path does match with a ArrayList of predefined file path library.
but there may be some difference between the original file path and path defined in the arraylist.
example---
ogiginal paths

```
\\10.45.34.56\\root\\hub\\data\\outgoing_20-09-2017_data.txt.zip
\\10.45.34.56\\root\\hub\\inbox\\outgoing_20-09-2017_inbox.txt.zip
\\10.45.34.56\\root\\hub\\inbox\\incoming_20_09_2017_inbox.txt.zip
```

sample file path string

```
OUTGOING_21_09_2017.txt.zip
incoming_08_89_2017.txt.zip
draft_08-09-2016.txt.zip
```

now i need to find out the approximately matched file path with the sample list

Comment: i have seen many algorithm for string similarity find out like Levenshtein etc pleaase suggest

Comment: What you mean "approximately"? Which parts of the path we should take into account when comparing, and which are not?

Answer (score 0):

You can split original file paths by "//", in result array take last element and compare it with your path strings.

Comment: yes but there is time stamp or some other parameter also added.

Comment: so, should we ignore them during comparing?

Comment: yes. purpose is i need to check if those given file are present in the server or not. these are auto generated report some times includes its parent folder name or time stamp in different format

Comment: "those given file" - you mean by name? which part of file name should we use to compare?